# IIS rewrite allows unwanted redirects from URL parameter

Tags: c#, .net, azure, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

We have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app hosted on Azure and IIS. For some purposes, like adding a trailing slash, we use URL rewrites. But this rule appears to cause a problem with unwanted redirects from URL parameter, so for example, https://example.com/http:/google.com will redirect to the Google site.

What happens is this: when the request enters the RewriteModule, it's looks like this:

```
http://rockstar-dev-web-01:80/http:/google.com
```

(a bit obfuscated, but you get the idea), but then it appears to be split on it's own into two parts and the second one is being processed. Once it hits the add the trailing slash rewrite, a 301 redirect is made. Here are logs to illustrate this behavior, as you can see it the end only the latter part of the URL is being processed:

> GENERAL_REQUEST_START SiteId="1922794053237", AppPoolId="rockstar-dev-web-01", ConnId="805308232052", RawConnId="8053080123152", RequestURL="http://rockstar-dev-web-01:80/https:/wp.pl", RequestVerb="GET"   20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START   ModuleName="FailedRequestsTracingModule"    20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END ModuleName="FailedRequestsTracingModule", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE"    20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START   ModuleName="RequestMonitorModule"   20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END ModuleName="RequestMonitorModule", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE"   20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START   ModuleName="IsapiFilterModule"  20:16:22.600
> FILTER_PREPROC_HEADERS_START      20:16:22.600
> FILTER_START  FilterName="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll"  20:16:22.600
> GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER    HeaderName="AspFilterSessionId", HeaderValue="", Replace="true" 20:16:22.600
> FILTER_SET_REQ_HEADER HeaderName="AspFilterSessionId:", HeaderValue=""    20:16:22.600
> FILTER_END    NotificationStatus="SF_STATUS_REQ_NEXT_NOTIFICATION"    20:16:22.600
> FILTER_PREPROC_HEADERS_END        20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END ModuleName="IsapiFilterModule", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE"  20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START   ModuleName="RewriteModule"  20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END ModuleName="RewriteModule", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE"  20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START   ModuleName="ARRHelper"  20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END ModuleName="ARRHelper", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE"  20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START   ModuleName="DynamicIpRestrictionModule" 20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END ModuleName="DynamicIpRestrictionModule", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START   ModuleName="ProcessMonitoringModule"    20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END ModuleName="ProcessMonitoringModule", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE"    20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START   ModuleName="DWASModule" 20:16:22.600
> GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER    HeaderName="HOST", HeaderValue="develop.rockstar.com", Replace="true"   20:16:22.600
> GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER    HeaderName="x-ms-http-forward", HeaderValue="", Replace="true"  20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END ModuleName="DWASModule", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START   ModuleName="AzureSlaModule" 20:16:22.600
> PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END ModuleName="AzureSlaModule", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 20:16:22.600
> GENERAL_REQUEST_HEADERS   Headers="Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
> Host: develop.rockstar.com
> Max-Forwards: 10
> TE: trailers
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0
> DNT: 1
> sec-gpc: 1
> sec-fetch-dest: document
> sec-fetch-mode: navigate
> sec-fetch-site: none
> sec-fetch-user: ?1
> X-ARR-LOG-ID: c57dc640-fe88-4a55-823c-3620113afe17
> DISGUISED-HOST: develop.rockstar.com
> X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID: rockstar-dev-web-01
> WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME: rockstar-dev-web-01.azurewebsites.net
> X-Forwarded-Proto: https
> X-AppService-Proto: https
> X-Forwarded-TlsVersion: 1.3
> X-Original-URL: /https://wp.pl
> X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL: /https://wp.pl
> 20:16:22.600
> URL_CACHE_ACCESS_START    RequestURL="/https:/wp.pl"

I have removed the rewrite rule and it doesn't allow anymore redirects, but that's not a long-term option. I have also tried to reshuffle the order of rewrites, but to no success - the problem still persists.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Based on your scenario and description, the URL rewrite rule you're using is inadvertently triggering a redirect when it shouldn't be. One common reason for this behavior is that the rewrite rule is too broad and is matching URLs that it shouldn't, such as URLs with parameters. you can try modifying your rewrite rule to be more specific so that it doesn't match URLs with parameters. For example, you can use a regular expression to match only URLs without parameters, or you can use a condition to check if the URL has a parameter before applying the rewrite rule.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thing is though, from logs it appears that the latter part of the URL (everything from the second http/https prefix) is being evaluated before it gets to the rewrite pipeline. And so, instead of "https://example.com/http:/google.com", only the "http:/google.com" part is being taken into account. I don't know why, maybe it is inbuilt behavior in IIS rewrite module, because we don't have a rule to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The URL parameter causing unexpected redirects is likely due to a misconfiguration in the URL rewrite rules. To exceed unwanted redirects from URL parameters, we need to ensure that the rewrite rules are properly configured to handle different types of URLs.

***To redirected URL rewriting in an ASP .NET Core MVC application hosted on Azure with IIS.***

- Below is my web.config which I have configured.

**web.config:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Redirect to add trailing slash -->
        <rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        
        <!-- Handle requests to the ASP.NET Core app -->
        <rule name="ASP.NET Core" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="yourAspNetCoreApp.dll/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <!-- ASP.NET Core handlers -->
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    
    <!-- ASP.NET Core module -->
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\yourAspNetCoreApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- The first rule redirects requests without a trailing slash to the same URL with a trailing slash (e.g., `example.com/page` to `example.com/page/`
- Second rule handles requests to the ASP.NET Core app, rewriting them to the appropriate handler.

***IIS Manager:***
[image]

- As per you mentioned from the above logs, the request URL `http://rockstar-dev-web-01:80/https:/wp.pl` is being split into two parts: `http://rockstar-dev-web-01:80/` and `https:/wp.pl`.
- Encode URL parameters properly to prevent them from being misinterpreted by the server. In the case of the example URL `http://rockstar-dev-web-01:80/https:/wp.pl`, the colon (`:`) in the URL parameter should be properly encoded as `%3A`.

[image]